# iPhone sdk call interception

Tags: iphone, core-telephony

We are developing a app .The function of the app is "when we got a call automatically we have to reply through text/voice message .So,can you tell us whether it possible in iPhone.If means guide us to build the app.

Thanks in advance ,

BrightRaj

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to access the phone in such a way with the current SDK. I guess it can be done on a jailbroken iPhone or on the Android platform.