# Can you hook into a phone call on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone sdk call interception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255205/iphone-sdk-call-interception)
>   [Can I launch my application from a call event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702701/can-i-launch-my-application-from-a-call-event)

Is their a way off hooking into the iphones call process with an app.

So every time a phone call is made on the iphone i can trigger some code to run within my app after they have approved it?

Is this possible?

Comment: hook into call process on iphone / trigger app on call iphone /trigger app on outgoing call iphone

Comment: Hi so its not possible to have iphone log geo location off a phone call, using a app. Their is now way to log that information during a phone call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone sdk call interception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255205/iphone-sdk-call-interception) or [Can I launch my application from a call event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702701/can-i-launch-my-application-from-a-call-event) or [Launching application on call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309445/launching-application-on-call).

Comment: Basically my phone got nicked and the guy ran up a £400 bill before i blocked the phone if i had an app that logged all the phone calls location after i lost it i could prove i didn't make those calls. I have heard that some providers do actually log this data but you need to be the police to access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its' possible, but you won't get through the appstore with this kind of stuff. Check out CoreTelephony, as described http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/12348-add-coretelephony-framework.html

Comment: Basically my phone got nicked and the guy ran up a £400 bill before i blocked the phone if i had an app that logged all the phone calls location after i lost it i could prove i didn't make those calls. I have heard that some providers do actually log this data but you need to be the police to access it.